# extract absolute url from webpage

Tags: php, curl

i am using this php code to extract all links from url but this gives mixed of absolute and relative but i want to convert all links into absolute links in this script only

```
   <?
$request_url ='http://www.qualitycodes.com';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);    // The url to get links from
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // We want to get the respone
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$regex='|<a.*?href="(.*?)"|';
preg_match_all($regex,$result,$parts);
$links=$parts[1];
foreach($links as $link){
    echo $link."<br>";
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

i want all url to be absolute

Answer (score 0):

Prepend the relative URLs with the absolut URL of the current page.

Comment: can u please suggest how. i tried by adding http req but got error

Comment: In PHP, you cannot add strings (well, you can, but you get a number as a result (due to implicit casting)). What you want is to concatenate strings. And what's this *http req* you are talking about? And what error did you get? Show the code of your attempt.